# Javascript: Need assistance with making a factory-ish function

Tags: javascript, this

I need something like so

```
function updateRender(ClassName){
   if(!(this.currentRender instanceof ClassName)){
         doPreprocessing();
         this.currentRender = new ClassName();
         doPostProcessing();
   }
}
```

So I would be able to call updateRender with a new render object, which can be different type.

```
updateRender( SolidRender );
updateRender( HollowRender );
updateRender( HollowRender ); //does nothing because currentRender is HollowRender
```

Comment: Is the above a valid javascript? I was writing psuedo-code. Didn't think I can do that

Comment: Yes, it's valid JavaScript, although `this` seems a bit out of place and I would call it `clazz` rather than `ClassName`.

Comment: why clazz instead of ClassName?

Comment: I wouldn't use `ClassName` because it's a reference to a class, not the name of a class. That leaves `Class`, which would work, but I decided to make it lowercase for some reason. `class` is a reserved keyword, so I changed it to `clazz`.

Comment: ClassName sounds like it could be a string, so I think Class would be a fitting name. I never heard of clazz before though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got your answer in the comments, so this is just an FYI:

You're using `this.currentRender`, which - if the function is in the global scope - will refer to a variable the global scope. I.e. to the `window` object of the browser. And putting things in global scope is very rarely a good idea.

Technically, you should put *all* your code in a single namespace or even inside a function that's invoked immediately so it doesn't pollute the global scope. However, you can start by simply getting the `currentRender` variable out of the global scope by doing this:

```
var updateRender = (function () {
    var currentRender = null;

    return function (klass) {
        doPreprocessing();
        currentRender = new klass();
        doPostProcessing();
    };

}());
```

the `updateRender` function will still be in the global scope, but at least the `currentRender` variable is safely hidden inside a closure, so only `updateRender` can change it (aka privileged access).

As for using `klass` instead of `Class`, that's entirely up to you. Using `klass` is just a common way of getting around the "`class` is a keyword" problem in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the top. The function is not in the global namespace. It is a prototype function for some object.